# How to replace a template of the blog post page in avada theme in wordpress with a new one?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I require to replace the blog post page in avada theme with a newly build page or customize the existing theme. Any idea about how that can be done ?

Actual site  url : https://www.wishtv.com/sports/college-basketball/kansas-becomes-latest-no-1-in-ap-top-25-tar-heels-fall-out/

Ongoing site's url : https://dev-wishtv.pantheonsite.io/news/hoosiers-rout-leathernecks-98-65-in-opening-night-hit/

Comment: Please refer tutorial of wordpress templating.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand but in your case try to use a plugin. >> https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/